# What are the consequences of using Sci-Hub?

Tags: publications, publishers, legal-issues, online-publication, sci-hub

A student of mine has told me about Sci-Hub, where people can download copyrighted scholarly articles for free.

I have cautioned him that it is illegal, but he challenged me asking me what would be the consequences for him if he only downloads files uploaded by others.

So my question is, what are the potential consequences of using Sci-Hub?

Comment: Theoretically, the answer depends on many factors, including your jurisdiction, your internet provider rules, and your University Honour code.  Practically, the consequences are likely to be nil.

Comment: The answer depends on the laws of the country. Here's an answer for Germany: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/86414/is-it-legal-to-use-sci-hub-cc-in-germany

Comment: *what are the consequences* - am I assuming correctly that you are interested mainly in the *legal* consequences?

Comment: I'm also interested in the consequences, both at personal and community levels, of _not_ using Sci-Hub.

Comment: Right now the main consequence is being unable to get papers. It has been broken of the time!..

Comment: Which country were you asking about?

Comment: I am mainly interested in European countries and USA

Comment: Using Sci Hub is like borrowing books from a library without checking them out: 1) It is stealing, 2) it's the same DB or very close to Athens, Jstor, etc. that you already have 3) Sci Hub is *way* easier to use 4) it's arguably less ethically wrong than outright stealing (from a book store or without a university license respectively). On the subject of theft, how 'bout them publishers? But I digress...

Comment: Scihub also often has quality pdfs, sometimes more easily readable by iphone pdf readers than university libraries.

Answer (score 56):

It's of questionable legality, but it's not going to lead to prosecution. For me personally using sci-hub has led to new research results in fields outside of my specialization that will (very likely) appear in leading peer reviewed journals. One problem I'm not sure about is whether it's wise to say in the acknowledgements: "I thank [Alexandra Elbakyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandra_Elbakyan) for setting up Sci-Hub without which the research results reported in this paper would have been impossible", in an Elsevier paper.

Using sci-hub therefore has at least the consequence of your personal scientific enlightenment, and possibly even of many other people who benefit from research you have been able to as a result of using sci-hub.

Comment: Wise or not, it's increasingly common to [thank Alexandra Elbakyan](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22thank+alexandra+elbakyan%22) in published acknowledgements, even (apparently) on an Elsevier journal. You can just use a generic phrase like "for her support", or "for help with the literature review" or "for her indirect assistance" as someone did.

Answer (score 12):

There would likely be no consequences for a student to use sci-hub. In fact, for a student to *not* use it is foolish, considering that much valuable research that could be used for school assignments is hidden behind paywalls that no student can be reasonably asked to pay.

I could see the argument being made against using sci-hub *for a professional research paper*, in which the user actually stands to receive some form of profit from their work. But a student can only gain knowledge and assignment completion, with no monetary profit from using this site.

The legality of the site itself is dubious, but there are not likely legal consequences for simply using the site, especially if there is no monetary gain for the user.

Morally, there is much to be said about academic monopolization. Too many publications and companies control knowledge, inflating prices to take advantage of already poor students with few other options. This was a legal question, not a moral one, so I will say no more about it, but I would not take action against the student if I were you.

Comment: There being no monetary gain for the user doesn't make it legal to use something acquired illegally - see https://law.stackexchange.com/a/33647/15133

Answer (score 6):

The consequences are **overwhelmingly positive**!

1. Gaining access to research papers one would probably not otherwise have access to.
2. Undermining the control major publishers (Elsevier etc.) have over access to scientific findings.
3. Contributing to a social norm of free access to scientific information.

There is effectively no possibility of your friend being sanctioned for downloading articles from Sci-Hub. I do not know of world states in which researchers have been penalized or sued in court for doing so - although, caveat: I have not followed the question of such legal action closely.

Comment: Sorry, your #2 is a deal breaker. While the system isn't perfect, it does get scientific findings both properly viewed and disseminated.

Comment: @Buffy: #2 is not necessary for scientific findings to be disseminated. Not sure what "properly viewed" means.

Comment: Hmmm. properly "reviewed". Garbage can also be disseminated, and is. If you don't believe the publishing system is valid, don't use it. But copyright has a valid purpose.

Comment: @Buffy: Why do we need Elsevier for journals with proper reviews? Academics do the reviews anyway, they/we would just do it in freely-accessible-content journals instead.

Comment: But that isn't Sci-Hub. I hold copyright on much of my own work. Sci-Hub can make it less valuable to me, the creator. Nevermind Elsevier. You are attacking copyright, not Elsevier.

Comment: @Buffy: You focused on #2. If you want to argue about copying restriction mechanisms, we can do that. I don't understand what you mean by your paper being "less valuable" because people can read it. Do you mean you want to be able to make money by charging people for reading it?

Answer (score 4):

Using Sci Hub can also be like reading books in a library without borrowing them: 1) Is it operating as the library intended? No and yes. 2) I agree that it's arguably less ethically wrong than outright stealing. After reading copious articles on a subject, I can then decide which articles I want to cite/include/research further. Impossible to gain such knowledge and familiarity with the subject if I had to purchase each paper.

As a teenager I would go to a Barnes and Noble and read another chapter of the same book every day till I finished it. Then on to new book. Was it stealing? I didn't really care because I couldn't afford to buy school lunch much less books. I see this much the same way.

Comment: Why "no and yes"? Libraries I know have tables and chairs where people sit and read.

Comment: And is "Barnes and Noble" a library? It sounds more like a bookstore.

Comment: Maybe you meant to write "bookstore" rather than "library"? I know it is a false friend in some languages. The comparison works better with bookstores anyway, since they are for-profit and selling books is their main source of profit.

Comment: Not a good comparison - if the bookstore wanted to prevent you from reading the book, they can seal it up. The same doesn't apply to SciHub, which is illegally accessing papers/books that the publishers explicitly do not want them to access.

Comment: Barnes and Noble is, indeed, a US bookstore chain. The commenter was not confusing bookstore with library. He was describing two scenarios, I believe.

Comment: @user111388 So what? I don't think that a core aspect of a library is that it has chairs and tables—the important thing is that it allows you to read literature for free, usually within a wide selection of topics. I have my own chair and table when I read articles on SciHub.

Answer (score -3):

Sci-Hub is not a repository of user-uploaded material. See e.g. [this explanation](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/04/whos-downloading-pirated-papers-everyone) - it uses institutional usernames and passwords to obtain the material. When you request a paper, if it's not already in the repository, Sci-Hub uses someone else's institutional access to get the paper. How Sci-Hub got those usernames and passwords is unknown. It's possible they were donated by Sci-Hub supporters, or they might have phished for them (remember also that it is almost certainly against your institutional policies to give out your username and password).

In other words you are correct and your student is wrong: Sci-Hub is illegal.

As for consequences, as in the linked article, if you are doing analysis of the papers themselves, then you're stuck because you can't publish data which you obtained illegally. Beyond that there's likely to be no consequences. There are simply too many people using the service. On a personal level it comes to one's moral values and how much one is willing to do something that's illegal, which I won't comment on.

In the long term if everyone decided to use the service then the publishing world will change massively, although it's complex enough that it's hard to forecast what actually will happen. Also, remember that the *modus operandi* of Sci-Hub isn't unique to academic publishing. Sci-Hub is a threat to all publishers of non-free electronic content, since it will probably work on *Wall Street Journal* articles and whatnot.

Comment: If everyone used Sci-hub "_institutions ... won't subscribe, after which Sci-Hub won't have access to the papers either_". Many publishers would then turn into open access, and other novel paywall-less, noncommercial publishing model(s) would appear as well.

Comment: @Orion OA would need to gain wider acceptance too (c.f. Jeffrey Beall saying gold OA is fundamentally not workable). It's hard to forecast. Let's just say the publishing world will change massively and leave it at that. I'll edit the "predictions" out of the answer.

Comment: Note that *Sci-hub is illegal* may mean two different things: (1) they are infringing the law by letting people download copyrighted material, or (2) *I* am infringing the law if I download copyrighted material from them. While (1) seems clear, (2) is much more debatable in my view.

Comment: Per https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/86414/is-it-legal-to-use-sci-hub-in-germany/112475#112475, (2) is not much more debatable, although it varies by country.

Comment: Using Sci-Hub is not universally illegal. In some states in the world it is, in some it's of questionable legality, in others it's perfectly legal. In some states it is not criminally prohibited but is cause for civil legal action (e.g. [in the US](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/7823/12209)), so it is kind of illegal but not in the police-and-jails sense. Anyway, your sweeping statement that using Sci-Hub is illegal is untrue.

Comment: @einpoklum The best part of that question is "A judge in NY found that viewing child porn on internet not criminal possession bc no possession" -- aka. streaming is not illegal, but downloading is, and this question asked about downloading.

Comment: Where is Sci-Hub illegal? No region tag was added to the question! Could we be victims of yet another case of Euro/Amero-centrism here?

Comment: @David pretty much anywhere with copyright law would suffice to default to "SciHub is illegal". Doesn't mean it is illegal, but it would be enough to take it as illegal until proven otherwise.

Comment: "you can't publish data which you obtained illegally" - Not  true, when you cite a paper, or use the attached data for re-analysis no-one will ask for you to prove you obtained the paper or the data legally.

Comment: @Ivana if you publish a paper and you use self-generated data, you'll need to describe how you acquired it, or your results won't be reproducible.